Are sums and products sufficient to show that two lists permute?
Consider the list of numbers $M = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$. I am writing an algorithm to check if a given list of numbers $N = (n_1,\dots,n_9)$, where $n_1,\dots,n_9 \in \mathbb N$, is a permutation of $M$.
I am aware that this can be posed as a valid anagram problem that can be solved in $O(n)$ time, where $n$ is the length of $M$. However, I am wondering if the following alternative method is provably correct.
I computed the sum and product of the numbers in $M$, which turned out to be $\sum_{i=1}^9 i = 45$ and $\prod_{i=1}^9 i = 362,880$ respectively, and the sum and product of the numbers in $N$, and then compared them. If the both the sums and products are equal, then I conclude that $M$ is a permutation of $N$. Otherwise, they are not permutations of each other.
I've tried to come up with counterexamples to this method, where the sum and products of $M$ and $N$ are equal but they are not permutations of each other, but I have failed so far. Instead, I am now trying to formally prove that the above method is correct, but I am not sure of a good way to start.
One way I think I can prove this is to show that the following feasibility problem has a unique solution:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{find} \quad & n_1,\dots,n_9 \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & n_1,\dots,n_9 \in \mathbb N \\
\quad & \sum_{i=1}^9 n_i = \sum_{i=1}^9 i = 45 \\
\quad & \prod_{i=1}^9 n_i = \prod_{i=1}^9 i = 362,880
\end{aligned}
$$
However, I am not really sure where to go from here either, so any advice would be appreciated.
